# Why Polymer Project (Web Components) isn't famous yet in comparison to other approach?

Tags: html, polymer, components, web-component, custom-element

It's been about a while Polymer version **2** is available out there, but

- *few* people talk about it
- *few* developers write about it in their blogs
- *few* developers share their workflow and their experiences

Polymer Project is powered by Google, and the team seems have impeccable philosophy behind it.

Beside lack of browser support, **Polyfills** are doing the job still fine.

By the way, It seems people don't prefer to switch on it and work on it although  Web components is an standard of the web.

There's a big *why* for me, there should be an explanation.

This is I think is related to Stackoverflow However I know many wouldn't like this kind of questions.

Answer (score 9):

First, it's actually a very new technology since Polymer 2 was officially released in May of 2017.

Second, the fact that it is supported by Google is not necessarily an advantage: web developers who want to rely on this company's products may prefer Angular, which is also promoted by Google and is much more mature and famous.

Third, the fact that it is founded on the *Web components standard* is not an advantage too:

- polyfills are *doing the job* (though not always) but their use adds a bit of complexity and can introduce a gap in therm of performance between the native and polyfilled implementation of Custom Element and Shadow DOM.
- developers who know Custom Elements and Shadow DOM may prefer to create ***Vanilla* web components** instead as they became very easy to design thanks to... Google :-) That's precisely the purpose of these new web standards.

Fourth, the *Material Design* flavor chosen for UI elements may not fit everyone's taste.

Fifth, version 2 is not fully compatible with version 1, which may bring some confusion for newcomers, and some disappointments for those who invested on the ephemeral version 1.

Finally, one can question if Polymer is a long-term framework or just a way to support the launch of the early standards (Custom Elements and Shadow DOM) proposed by Google, and promote their adoption.

---

*PS*

Some of the above points are only assumptions.

Personally, I started using Polymer 1 during a few months, then I switched to *Vanilla* Custom Elements.

Comment: I have pretty much the same feeling, or assumptions. In addition, 4) material design is not exclusive to Polymer. I'm also thinking of moving away from Polymer backed components to vanilla. That's somewhat the message I can get from last Polymer Summit - the goal of Polymer is to close the gap between the platform and applications, and reduce itself to zero. Let's see what's next in the coming Polymer Summit in Copenhagen, https://summit.polymer-project.org/schedule

Answer (score 1):

because of that is harder to implement other than material design or bootstrap or other designing frameworks

bootstrap is easily implemented and no other things to do with it like adding javascript with each of components and each component have its own styles

but afterall polymer is good project for whom who has a better designing skills and bootstrap and other is'nt requires higher designing skills

Answer (score 1):

Even though Polymer is getting closer and closer to native Vanilla web components the fact that they are still not fully supported across all Browsers makes it not really practical to use.
I personally like the idea that this(Polymer) might end one day with a somewhat seamless transfer to native components.

What I also picked up during talks and conversations with fellow developers is that React is way bigger in the states while Developers in Europe tend to choose rather Polymer. Why exactly that is I do not really know, but I believe that there are many factors influencing it and that it can't be pinpointed to a specific disadvantage or advantage of one of these libraries.
As Supersharp already mentioned Polymer is still pretty new compared to other libraries such as Angular & React. But the developer community is growing from year to year which was especially emphasized at the last Polymer summit in Copenhagen where everything was about "The Platform". This turned out to be the community, web standards and everything around it rather than a total Polymer worship which I felt pretty pleasant.

On last thing to add.
Although, Polymer might be backed by Google the team working on it is relatively small. **Youtube just switched to a 100% Polymer** and what I picked up is that the team that made this happen is way bigger than the actual team developing the platform.(We are talking about a handful people here).

Answer (score 0):

I use Polymer 2 for a small demo project mid 2017 (RC2, not final one), was nice and enjoyable. For my point of view, it is easier than Angular (1.6), but I don't have a lot of experience with it.

> Pro

- I like this idea of a component for each problem
- Easy to split data (properties) and template
- Easy use of events

> Con

- CSS rules was really intuitive

> Polymer 2 Example Element

```
<dom-module id="input-array-element">
    <template>
        <h3>Inputs Array</h3>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{technology}}">
            <input type="text" value="{{item.label::input}}">[[item.label]]<br/>
        </template><br>
    </template>
    <script>
    class InputArrayElement extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() { return 'input-array-element'; }

        static get properties() {
            return {
                technology : {
                    type: Array,
                    value: [
                        {id:"php", label:"PHP", selected:false},
                        {id:"js", label:"Javascript", selected:false},
                        {id:"html", label:"HTML", selected:false},
                        {id:"css", label:"CSS", selected:false},
                    ],
                    notify: true
                }
            }
        }

        ready() {
            super.ready();
            this.addEventListener("technology-changed", function(e){
               console.log(e); 
            });
        }

    }

    window.customElements.define(InputArrayElement.is, InputArrayElement);        
    </script>
</dom-module>
```